# Python program to delete a specific line in a text file

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file Thailand_Rectangle2_National Parks.txt with the following lines.

```
1
2
3
4
5
dy 0.5965
7
```

Now, I want to delete the 6th line in this text file.

For that, I am using the following python code.

```
f = open("C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop/Thailand_Rectangle2_National Parks.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
```

So, I saved all the lines of this text file in 'lines'.

```
line6 = lines[5]
t = line6[:2]
f.close()
```

So, now, I have 't' = "dy" . Now,

```
if t == "dy":
    f = open("C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop/Thailand_Rectangle2_National Parks.txt","w")
    for line in lines:
        if lines[5] != line6:
            f.write(line)

f.close()
```

So, if the condition 't' = "dy" satisfies, then I will open this text file for writing and I will print all the lines except line6 (which means line6 is deleted from this text file).

Unfortunately, I am getting the lines in this text file as blank, which means no lines are printed as outputs.

But, I want the lines in the text file as given below.

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
```

How can I solve this issue ?

I want to use only Python programming to solve this issue; since this is a small task of a major work.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as a duplicate because although the title of the two questions are the same, the other question does not ask how to delete a specific line number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that `lines[5]` will *always* be equal to `line6`. You never modified the sixth line in `lines`, so `line6` and `lines[5]` are still equal. Thus, the condition `lines[5] != line6` will always fail.

If you want to always remove the sixth line from your file, you can use `enumerate`. For example:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

with open("file.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for pos, line in enumerate(lines):
        if pos != 5:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error in your code was already pointed out, but instead of comparing the content of each line, I recommend you simply compare the line number or use `startswith`. Otherwise you are doing a lot of unneeded string comparisons, which can be costly.

Other improvements could be to handle your file using `with`, opening the file only once and allowing to delete multiple lines at once.

```
# 'r+' allows you to read and write to a file
with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    # First read the file line by line
    lines = f.readlines()

    # Go back at the start of the file
    f.seek(0)

    # Filter out and rewrite lines
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith('dy'):
            f.write(line)

    # Truncate the remaining of the file
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: This is incorrect. After `readlines()` the file cursor is at the end of the file, so all writes append to the end, thus the final file will have _more_ lines than it originally had. Also, `startwith()` should be `startswith()`.

Comment: @nh2 Thanks for pointing out. I don't remember what I thought at the time, but it simply seems I forgot to seek(0) after reading all lines. You can have a look at the fixed solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your logic and variable names. You're checking if lines[5] is not equal to line6, everytime in your loop. Which it is, because it IS that exact line. You want the check the current line:

```
if t == "dy":
    f = open("C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop/Thailand_Rectangle2_National Parks.txt","w")
    for line in lines:
        if line != line6: # <- Check actual line!
            f.write(line)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that line6 == lines[5], so the condition
if lines[5] != line6:
is never true and thus you never write anything to the file